# Epson tm u200b bitmap

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, epson

I'm working with a Epson Tm U200B dot matrix printer (receipt printer). I got a template of the receipt in excel (some text and 2 images). It prints ok from excel, but now I'm doing and .net app to print from there.

The printer works on an COM serial port.

What:

- Print a logo and some text in te same line: "[LOGO]           *THANK YOU*"

What have I tried:

- On windows I tried the Printer object that comes with .NET (such as e.Drawing.DrawString, etc). The printer is ultra slow using this and it won't use the correct font.
- Installed POS net

  - [Microsoft Point Of Sale (PoS.net) Download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5355)
  - [MS Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923964)
  - [Epson OPOS Drivers](http://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=2345&scat=39&pcat=3)
  - After all this, the TM U200B is not supported. :(

I took source code from many websites, forums, and here but nothing.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474294/esc-pos-codes-for-printing-image-data-in-page-mode) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099239/printing-a-bit-map-image-to-pos-printer-via-comport-in-c-sharp)
- [The Nicholas Piasecki's article](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/12/sending-a-bit-image-to-an-epson-tm-t88iii-receipt-printer-using-c-and-escpos/)
- I've read about ESC/POS command but no luck. I can't get my printer to print a BMP logo.
- Couldn't find any "ESC * m nL nH d1...dk" sample to work with.

I'm hopeless and exhaust, trying almost anything I found on the internet... If someone have some experience with this, please help me.

Comment: directprinting or printdoc class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, short answer:

I bought a Tm U220A which supports ESC/POS. Use PrintBitmap() function (OPOS.net) and reverse feed 2 lines, and print the text.

I know it's not the perfect workaround, but it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain I spent all of last weekend [working out receipt printing from a webbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082482/how-to-print-a-receipt-through-receipt-printer-from-web-page-aspx/16756460#16756460).

As I mention in the above answer download jZebra library, it has a sample.html page and I recall seeing a Print Picture function.

Comment: Today I purchased a new model that suppots OPOS/POS.Net (u200 doesn't). I'm waiting for the mail. :)

Comment: Nice one:) If you can keep me posted it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: The TM U220A it's AWESOME!! It printed text and bmp's. It has reverse feed and 128Kb if you want to upload some logos (It will stream any bitmap just passing out the filename). PoS.Net is well implemented but the examples don't have a lot of comments.